# Formalizing the distribution of a random vector with independent components

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, notation

Let's say I have a random vector $T = \{ t_1,\ldots, t_n \}$ where each component $t_i$ is independent and follows a Bernoulli distribution $t_i \sim \text{Bern}(p_i)$. What's the correct formalization of the distribution $\mathcal{T}$ of the whole random vector $T$? Basically I wrote $T \sim \mathcal{T}$ specifying that $\mathcal{T}$ is the distribution of the whole vector $T$ but without formalizing further. It is correct to write $\mathcal{T} = 
\{ \text{Bern}(p_1), \dots, \text{Bern}(p_n) \}$ ?

Comment: Usually the $\{\dots\}$ notation is used for sets, not ordered tuples.  I might write that $T\sim\operatorname{Bern}(p_1)\times\cdots\times\operatorname{Bern}(p_n)$ in this case, but it is pretty pedantic, and would feel happier if I actually used the product measure fact in the next paragraph or so.  Otherwise I'd just say the components were independently distributed with $t_i\sim\operatorname{Bern}(p_i)$

Comment: Maybe I can just assign $\mathcal T = \text{Bern}(p_1) \times \dots \times \text{Bern}(p_n)$, and later use $T \sim \mathcal{T}$?

Comment: That could work.